# Mass access protection in apache2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

For Congestion due to frequency(many) access
Are there any good apache module?

I wanna response 503 in the circumstance.

I've found http://sourceforge.net/projects/moddosdetector/

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your own question.

Comment: yeah , it's little yes . But, I wanna get more solutions for comparition :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) provides a lot of application firewalling functionality including [DOS protection](http://blog.cherouvim.com/simple-dos-protection-with-mod_security/).